# Trouble with D3.js and browserify

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to bundle my javascript code with the latest versions of D3.js (4.10.2) and browserify, but it doesn't work. The error appears in the request functions of d3.json and d3.csv. The files can't be loaded and i get the following error: "Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0". I think it is configuration problem, because without browserify the code works great. I tried serveral solutions, like https://github.com/vigetlabs/blendid/issues/17, but unfortunately without success. I'm really confused!

gulpfile.js:

```
const babel = require('babelify');
const browserify = require('browserify');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gutil = require('gulp-util');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', function () {

  return browserify({
    entries: ['./src/js/index.js'],
    extensions: ['.js'],
    paths: ['./node_modules', './src/js/']
  })
    .transform(babel)
    .bundle()
    .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
    .pipe(source('index.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify']);
```

File structure:

```
/src
  /css
  /data
  /js
  index.html
```

File loading:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, 'data/file1.json')
  .defer(d3.json, 'data/file2.json')
  .await((error, file1Result, file2Result) => { ... });
```

Maybe you guys have an idea!

Comment: Can you show us the lines of code that load the JSON files? It could be a path issue. Without seeing the code it's going to be hard to tell though.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question!

Comment: What are the contents of the JSON file? Can you post the first few lines (or a minimal example which reproduces the problem)?

Comment: "Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0" would suggest that one of your JSON files is not in proper JSON format. But that's only a guess.

Comment: Trust me, the content is well-formated. There is no problem with the JSON files.

Comment: Might be worth checking the network tab of your browser's web inspect to see where `data/file1.json` and `data/file2.json` are attempted to be loaded from. Perhaps they are 404ing?

Comment: You are right! :)

TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from //localhost:80data/file1.json
    at <anonymous>:1:904
    at module.exports.ClientR
    ...

There is a missing slash in the URL. It only works, if I insert the complete path in file loading functions. So it is a configuration problem in my gulpfile.js. But where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution for my problem: https://github.com/d3/d3-request/issues/24#issuecomment-328945696

It works for me, but it's only a hack!

I hope there will be a permanent solution soon.